# Are predictions on scikit-learn models thread-safe?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, thread-safety

Given some classifier (SVC/Forest/NN/whatever) is it safe to call `.predict` on the same instance concurrently from different threads?

From a distant point of view, my guess is they do not mutate any internal state. But I did not find anything in the docs about it.

Here is a minimal example showing what I mean:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X, y = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=True)

# Some model. Might be any type, e.g.:
clf = svm.SVC()
clf = RandomForestClassifier(),
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs')

clf.fit(X, y)


def use_model_for_predictions():
    for _ in range(10000):
        clf.predict(X[0:1])


# Is this safe?
thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=use_model_for_predictions)
thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=use_model_for_predictions)
thread_1.start()
thread_2.start()
```

Comment: Have you considered opening an issue in scikit-learn github repo? developers there are very friendly and usually quick. This is an interesting question, please provide the answer here if you manage to find one there.

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan Thanks, I followed your suggestion and just created [an issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18530).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290942/is-the-predict-proba-method-of-scikit-learns-sgdclassifier-thread-safe), the `predict` and `predict_proba` methods should be thread safe as they only call NumPy, they do not affect model itself in any case so answer to your question is yes.

You can find some info as well in replies [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/scikit-learn-general@lists.sourceforge.net/msg06544.html).

For example in [naive bayes](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/naive_bayes.py) the code is following:

```
def predict(self, X):
    """
    Perform classification on an array of test vectors X.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)
    Returns
    -------
    C : ndarray of shape (n_samples,)
        Predicted target values for X
    """
    check_is_fitted(self)
    X = self._check_X(X)
    jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
    return self.classes_[np.argmax(jll, axis=1)]
```

You can see that the first two lines are only checks for input. Abstract method `_joint_log_likelihood` is the one that interests us, described as:

```
@abstractmethod
def _joint_log_likelihood(self, X):
    """Compute the unnormalized posterior log probability of X
    I.e. ``log P(c) + log P(x|c)`` for all rows x of X, as an array-like of
    shape (n_classes, n_samples).
    Input is passed to _joint_log_likelihood as-is by predict,
    predict_proba and predict_log_proba.
    """
```

And finally for example for multinominal NB the function looks like ([source](http://ethen8181.github.io/machine-learning/text_classification/naive_bayes/naive_bayes.html)):

```
def _joint_log_likelihood(self, X):
    """
    Compute the unnormalized posterior log probability of X, which is
    the features' joint log probability (feature log probability times
    the number of times that word appeared in that document) times the
    class prior (since we're working in log space, it becomes an addition)
    """
    joint_prob = X * self.feature_log_prob_.T + self.class_log_prior_
    return joint_prob
```

You can see that there is nothing thread unsafe in `predict`. Of course you can go through codes and check that for any of those classifiers :)